# How to import Sleep function from kernel32?

Tags: c#, .net, dllimport

I have to import kernel32.dll from my windows forms application to use the Sleep function.
In VB.net,I am using the below code.

```
Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
```

How to convert the same in c#?

Comment: No you don't need to do this at all. The .net framework offers sleep functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Using System.Runtime.InteropServices;  

....

public class NativeMethods
{

    [DllImport("kernel32")]
    public static extern void Sleep(uint dwMilliseconds);
}
```

Comment: When I tried this ,I am getting the error "The type or namespace name DLLImport could not be found". Shall I add any assembly reference for this?

Comment: This is wrong. `long` is a signed 64 bit type. I fixed it for you.

Comment: @Marko: Thanks a lot.

Comment: @sowjanya Actually Marko got this wrong and my edit fixed it. The answer from dotctor was accurate all along. And you should not be p/invoking at all. If you simply have to accept a p/invoke answer, then give the rep to the answerer that actually got it right!! But don't use p/invoke at all, as I explain in my answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can p/invoke the function in kernel32 if you wish, as other answers show. However, it is almost certainly a mistake to do so. Judging by the form of your `Declare` statement I think your code pre-dates .net.

In .net you should call [`Thread.Sleep`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t.aspx). Where the platform provides the required functionality use it. The documentation says:

> This method calls the Sleep function from the Windows system APIs.

It's always cleaner and preferable to use the platform. Only use p/invoke when there is no platform provided way to reach the functionality.

Answer (score 2):

You can see the documents of [PInvoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.sleep)

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern void Sleep(uint dwMilliseconds);

// code added by g. sharp @ http://www.paradisim.net
public class MainApp
{
    [STAThread]
    public static void Main()
    {
        Sleep(U2000);  // pause for two seconds
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000); // does the same thing
    }
}
```

Comment: I apologise for doing the work to Marko's answer. Had I not done that then I guess you'd have the accept. I think it was right for me to do a good deed and fix an erroneous post. The thing is, sometimes askers know so little that they can't make a good judgement on what to accept.

Comment: No problem man, Good is what helps the community, Reputation is just a game :) @DavidHeffernan